# Something fun going on with unicode and python requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, python-requests

Firstly note that `u'\xc3\xa8'` is the python2 unicode string with 2 code-points, `Ã` and  `¨`. Next note that `'\xc3\xa8'` is the python2 byte str which represents the utf8 encoding of the character `è`. So `u'\xc3\xa8'` and `'\xc3\xa8'`, despite looking very similar are 2 very different beasts.

Now, if we try accessing `https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premièr-cru-brocard-75cl` in a browser all should go well.

If I define in a ipython session:

```
unicode_url = u'https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premièr-cru-brocard-75cl'
```

then I can print it and see the same thing I entered into the URL bar of the browser, great. Let's try and fetch this with python requests.

First, I naively just try throwing the unicode url to see if requests can just deal with it: `requests.get(unicode_url)`. Nope, 404, ok no problem, URLs should be encoded, so I try `requests.get(unicode_url.encode('utf8'))`. Nope 404 again. No problem, maybe I need to do the URL encoding too, so I try `requests.get(urllib.quote(unicode_url.encode('utf8')))`....It doesn't like that at all.

However, recalling the similarities between the unicode and byte str objects I mentioned at the start, I also tried:

```
  requests.get('http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premiÃ¨r-cru-brocard-75cl')
```

and to my surprise it works and gives a successful 200.

What is going on here with requests?

**EDIT: just as another experiment (in a Scrapy shell this time)**

```
   from scrapy.http import Request
   unicode_url = u'https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premièr-cru-brocard-75cl'
   fetch(Request(unicode_url))
```

Absolutely no problems! So Why do Scrapy and the browser deal with it without issue but not python-requests? and why does the alternate url work in python-requests but not the browser or Scrapy.

**Latin1 vs UTF8**

It's also true that

```
print unicode_url.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
u'https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premiÃ¨r-cru-brocard-75cl'
```

In general, I belive it's true that for latin unicode chars only, if you have a unicode str like `u'\xe8'` then you can convert it to a byte str of the same form by encoding to latin1, i.e. `u'è'=u'\xe8'` and `u'\xe8'.encode('latin1') = '\xe8'` (the object on the right being a byte str encoding in latin1 with the same form as the unicode code point representing the `è`)

So

```
In [95]: print u'è'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
Ã¨
```

and similarly,

```
In [94]: print u'Ã¨'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
è
```

I wonder if the culprit is

```
def prepare_url(self, url, params):
    """Prepares the given HTTP URL."""
    #: Accept objects that have string representations.
    #: We're unable to blindly call unicode/str functions
    #: as this will include the bytestring indicator (b'')
    #: on python 3.x.
    #: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/2238
    if isinstance(url, bytes):
        url = url.decode('utf8')
    else:
        url = unicode(url) if is_py2 else str(url)
```

from `requests/models.py`.

Comment: Do you have a `# coding: utf-8` line in the first two lines of the file?

Comment: Is this python 2.7? Can you add the `python-2.7` (or similar) tag? ....and then promptly move to python 3 where unicode support has been fixed? (smile)

Comment: @tdelaney it's taking place in an ipython shell, so I assume 'utf-8' is the default encoding. I added the tag too.

Comment: I don't use the ipython shell so can't spell out the exact mechanism, but it looks like you got the utf-8 bytes as separate characters and it only looks right in the shell because its also utf-8 encoded. Taking a smaller test, is `len(u"premièr")` 7 or 8?

Comment: @tdelaney It is 7

Comment: You are ruining my best theories!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed something odd:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: s = requests.Session()

In [3]: unicode_url = u'https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premièr-cru-brocard-75cl'

In [4]: s.get(unicode_url)
Out[4]: <Response [404]>

In [5]: s.get(unicode_url)
Out[5]: <Response [200]>
```

Seems to work in a session the second time around!

Possibly can say this is actually about cookies. The first request is without cookies and the webserver 404s because of that whilst still setting some session cookies. The next request sends the cookies and the webserver 200s.

BUT, notice that the second request now does not need a redirect; you could replace the second request with `s.get(unicode_url, allow_redirects=False)` and still get a 200, not a 302. Whereas the first request goes through a redirect chain. Hence the only reason it works now is that redirection is being sidestepped with cookies. This indicates the encoding issues are taking place somewhere in the redirect chain.

Note: This is exactly the same as in a clean session of Chrome with cookies cleared. If you clear cookies then go to the url it will 404. If you re-enter it and try again it will 200 with no problems (cookies were set by your first request and the troublesome redirect that led to the 404 was avoided)

**There is one weird thing too:**

```
In [11]:   requests.get(u'http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premiÃ¨r-cru-brocard-75cl')
Out[11]: <Response [200]>
```

despite no cookies/sessions. I am struggling to understand that. The location header of the redirect in this case looks like:

```
 'Location':  'http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premi\xc3\xa8r-cru-brocard-75cl?langId=44&storeId=10151&krypto=dZB7Mt97QsHQQ%2BGMpb1iMZwdVfmbg%2BbRUdkh%2FciAItm7%2F4VSUi8NRUiszN3mSofKSCyAv%2F0QRKSsjhHzoo1x7in7Ctd4vzPIDIW5CcjiksLKE48%2BFU9nLNGkVzGj92PknAgP%2FmIFz63xpKhvPkxbJrtUmwi%2FUpbXNW9XIygHyTA%3D&ddkey=http%3Agb%2Fgroceries%2Fchablis%2Fchablis-premi%C3%83%C2%A8r-cru-brocard-75cl'
```

i.e. we have the utf8 encoded u'è' instead of latin1 encoded.

**Summary**

Given that the first request (the request that actually has no cookies and relies on redirects) fails in every platform I have tried - Chrome, Scrapy, python-requests - I would put this down to a bug on the host server itself. It latin1 encodes it's location header in the redirect, but wants utf8 encoded URLs and 404s when the browser actually requests that redirect location URL, because the server was actually expecting a utf8 encoded URL. It should really be utf8 encoding the location header of it's redirect response in order to be consistent with the URL encoding it is using.

This is why when you cheat and use `u'http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premiÃ¨r-cru-brocard-75cl'` you actually end up with the correct utf8 encoded location header in the redirect, because `u'https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premiÃ¨r-cru-brocard-75cl'.encode('latin1')` is `'https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premi\xc3\xa8r-cru-brocard-75cl'`, which happens to be the correct utf8 encoded byte str of `u'https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premièr-cru-brocard-75cl'`, so when the browser redirects it works.

If you have cookies set from visiting the URL already or perhaps somewhere else on the website, you sidestep the need for a redirect, and avoid the broken redirect process.

See also https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/eae38b8d131e8b51c3daf3583e69879d1c02f9a4/requests/sessions.py#L101-L114 for how this works in python3 requests.

Answer (score 0):

The matter is that the URL on the site actually uses latin1 encoding for representing the  "è" character - and for some reason, the Python 2 requests library, in its attempt to "clean-up the url automatically" before making the call, encodes the "è" character in utf-8 - that is what causes the 404 error.

Trying to encode the unicode_url in latin1 before calling requests.get does not help either - it attempts to decode that to unicode before its "clean up", and them errors on the invalid utf=8 sequence that is the code for "è" when using latin-1 (the " \xe8" char).

At this ppint is worth noting that requests with Python 3 also works with no problem at all - as the language automates text handling, requests needs less dancing back and forth the text encoding - and on my first attempt on Python 3 I just got:

```
In [13]: requests.get(unicode_url)
Out[13]: <Response [200]>
```

Now, a workaround with Python 2.7 and requests seens hard to come by - without monkey patching some specific code in requests so that it does the right thing. However, even in Python2, using your unicode_url manually encoded into latin-1, and using `urllib.open` instead of requests also work  - if you really need Python 2, maybe that is the best approach for you:

```
In [28]: a  = urllib.urlopen(unicode_url.encode("latin1"))

In [29]: a.code
Out[29]: 200
```

(Really - if this is just some script you are doing for some particular tooling, I'd advice just to switch to Python 3.6 - it will be a lot easer to handle the data when you get to it as well)

Comment: (I've tried a bit further to monkey-patch requests in Python 2.7 beore making the request, but it seems to be a lost cause - rally, just do urllib.urlopen in Python 2 or change to Python 3)

Comment: Thanks. How did you figure out the website is using latin1? (I had previously looked at the headers and it suggested utf8). So is this a bug in the requests lib that should be reported to their issues page? And could you point me to the relevant bits of requests code doing the "clean up" please.

Comment: Also why does the alternative URL from my OP work with requests?

Comment: Also: `In [6]: a.readlines()
Out[6]: ['<html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: 4373853497355116658</body></html>']`....Changing to python3 is not an option on this project.

Comment: Futher to this `fetch(Request(unicode_url.encode('latin1')), dont_filter=True)` in Scapy fails, whereas `fetch(Request(unicode_url.encode('utf8')), dont_filter=True)` succeeds, so I'm not completely convinced the site uses latin1.

Comment: "scapy" and "scrapy" are different projects.

Comment: And for the "latin1" part - the site contents are probably utf-8, it is the URL encoding that I think is latin1 - because urls are usually tied to web-ervers which use more ancient configuration options - Latin1 is used by defaulton windows for European languages, and was the way to try to "sneak in" accented characters that might "just work"  on the early web. 

Scrapy may be doing other crazy transforms on the URL string. (Requests for one, converts a byte string to unicode again internally, with utf-8 hardcoded)

Comment: Yes, that was a typo obviously. I really can't change to python 3 in this project. It's a huge django/scrapy project.

Comment: Even chrome seems to encode the URL in utf8 though - I watched the request in the network tab, and it was for `https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premi%C3%A8r-cru-brocard-75cl`, which is the percent encoding of the utf8 encoding of the URL...

Comment: This is even true in chrome/firefox/scrapy (make sure cookies cleared first). It's not specific to requests at all it seems. Cookies were fooling me earlier, because if they are set, then a redirect process is avoided and it works in requests too or anywhere else you like. If they are not set then it breaks even on Chrome and you'll get a 404 the first time around. It sets a location header that is latin1 encoded but seems to want a utf8 encoded URL really.